# flake8 2.4.0 not support pep8 1.6.2 version?

Tags: python, pip, pep8, flake8

Recently I have updated `flake8` from `2.3.0` to `2.4.0` by pip, and `pep8` up to `1.6.2`, now I can't run `flake8` due to `2.4.0` not support `>1.6` `pep8`.

Is there any way to downgrade `pep8` to a previous version by pip?
Bug Put upper cap on dependencies. The caps for `2.4.0` are:

```
pep8 < 1.6 (Related to GitLab#35)
mccabe < 0.4
pyflakes < 0.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last `pep8` release before 1.6 was 1.5.7 (see the [full list of releases](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/releases)); install that with `pip` by using a pin:

```
pip install --force pep8==1.5.7
```

You'll see something like:

```
$ pip install --force pep8==1.5.7
Collecting pep8==1.5.7
  Downloading pep8-1.5.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pep8
  Found existing installation: pep8 1.6.2
    Uninstalling pep8-1.6.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pep8-1.6.2

Successfully installed pep8-1.5.7
```

Alternatively, let `pip` figure out the last version before 1.6 for you:

```
pip install --force "pep8<1.6"
```

Also see [issue 35](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/35) in the flake8 repository; the alternative is to downgrade `flake8`:

```
pip install --force flake8==2.3.0
```

A fix for `pep8` is [under way](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/code-quality/2015-March/000515.html), hopefully soon we can find a way out of the current quagmire.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install pep8 by following command:

```
pip install "pep8>=1.5,<1.6"
```

This will install the latest version of pep8 but less than 1.6 and greater than 1.5. If you face any problem, first you can uninstall pep8, and then install it using above command.

Currently I am using `flake8 2.4.0` and `pep8 1.5.7` and it is running with out any problem.